# Hi I want to run a Test Plan in Jmeter......details below

Tags: jmeter

The criteria is that I have to run it with 1 user in the thread group and I have to run 15 iterations, also the test should run for an hour.
Can someone please help me with the settings that I am supposed to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run your test for 15 iterations then your thread group configurations should be like:

[image]

If you want to run your test for an hour:

[image]

Comment: But jahan I want to run it for an hour with 15 iterations....so then how should I set both? ....also can u tell me where can I understand the concept of pacing and think time?.....thanks a lot for answering

Comment: Your test will be finished after the 15 iterations have executed whatever your test durations. I suggest you to see the [Apache JMeter User Manuals](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers). To understand the concept of pacing and think time, see the [Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#timers)

Comment: Yeah I've seen that I still don't understand maybe cause I'm totally new to Jmeter that's why...in timers I specifically don't understand constant throughout timer... Anyways ...thanks for ur help

Comment: Constant Throughput timer allows you to maintain the throughput of your application server (requests/sec).It will let you control the flow of requests to be sent.